# How to delete till backward in vim

Tags: vim

I know how to delete until a char forward, like using `dtx` to delete till the `x` char from current cursor onwards. But how can I to do that backwards?

Say I have the following:

```
"abc I want to delete back to I"
```

And the cursor is at the end of the line, I want it to be `"abc "`.

Comment: try in command mode `0f d$`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

In general, capital letters reverse. So we have:

- <kbd>t</kbd> do something until a character
- <kbd>T</kbd> do something BACKWARDS until a character
- <kbd>f</kbd> do something until and including a character
- <kbd>F</kbd> do something BACKWARDS until and including a character

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem is not how to remove till/to (`T/F`) the char backwards. You need delete the char under cursor too , in your case, the last `I`. leaving `abc<space>` at the end.

#### option 1:  (3 key strokes)

You can  move to the first `I` backwards, than `D`:

```
FID
```

#### option 2:  (4 key strokes)

or move cursor to the beginning, do it forwardly.

```
0FID
```

#### option 3:  (4 key strokes)

you can do an extra `x`.

```
dFIx
```

#### option 4: (4 key strokes)

with `v`:

```
vFIx
```

Answer (score 1):

With cursor at end of line in normal mode, do <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>T</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>.